# How to define two constant labels and their values in Avalanche metrics generator for Prometheus performance testing?

Tags: prometheus

I want to define two constant labels with two static values , I refered official blog,
https://blog.freshtracks.io/load-testing-prometheus-metric-ingestion-5b878711711c

Also using help,  docker run quay.io/freshtracks.io/avalanche --help

I got to know that it's like below , but I tried with several combinations of it  but I'm not sure how to define it.

```
--const-label=CONST-LABEL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define like below.

```
const-label=LNAME1=labelValue1 --const-label=username=sammy
```

So both label name and value remains same via series.

```
docker run -it -d -p 9001:9001 --name MyAvalanche quay.io/freshtracks.io/avalanche --label-count=2 --const-label=LNAME1=labelValue1 --const-label=username=sammy --metric-count=5 --metricname-length=2 --series-count=4 --remote-batch-size=15 --remote-requests-count=1 --remote-write-interval=123ms --port=9001 --remote-url=http://myremoteurl/api/prom/push --remote-tenant=Mytenant-prod
```